# Copy/Pasting input in terminal does not work in Swift

Tags: swift, terminal, command-line-arguments

I am developing a command line tool app in Swift and when I paste input in `Terminal` or even in `Console` of Xcode it does not work. I have to type all the input every time. Here is what I am doing.

Printing Message: `print("Enter the file path:"`

and getting user input of path using following method

```
func getInput() -> String {
    let keyboard = FileHandle.standardInput
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData
    let strData = String(data: inputData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    return strData.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.newlines)
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

That was my mistake. I was taking explicitly taking input from keyboard. The other easiest way is to take input through `readLine()`. That worked for me.